# Getting trouble with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I'm using jQuery and PHP for my project,application is running quite well in all browsers except in IE(currently I've tested in IE-8).Javascript file is not showing any effect on IE,I saw the source code of web page,javascript stuff which I've written is there but it is not showing any effect.Is there any functions in jQuery which does not work in IE ? If so,please list them,another this what might be the problem,HTML or CSS? If it is then,all my alignments are working perfectly in other browsers.What might be went wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support some JS functions like tracking the user location etc.We must aware of fine CSS and valid HTML while working with IE.Check these issues in your page,then test once.

Comment: Ya,I've used finding geolocation script in my page,after removing that script my page is working fine in IE also.But how to find geolocation using IE??